# removing duplicates using 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove duplicate ID's in a sheet. For example here is a few rows of data

```
ID   |  Department |  Sales   | Update Date
1    | Sales       | 100      | 
2    | Marketing   | 100      | 
2    | Marketing   | 200      | 30/06/2015
2    | Marketing   | 300      | 05/07/2015
```

I want to remove the duplicate ID's but base this on the update date column.  So I want to only have the following remaining:

```
ID   |  Department |  Sales   | Update Date
1    | Sales       | 100      | 
2    | Marketing   | 300      | 05/07/2015
```

So it checks for the latest update row of that ID and removes the others.

Any advice on using VBA or a macro to do this would be great as it will form part of a automated script.

Comment: Go through the rows (top to bottom) and gather in an array for each ID the maximum update date. Then go throw the rows again and delete those records that do not match your array.

Comment: @Ralph unfortunately I am not too great with arrays, still studying on how to use them

Comment: Then add another column next to `Update Date` in which you ask Excel to calculate the maximum date for you. Something like `=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5=A2;$D$2:$D$5))`. For more details read this: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/11/19/using-max-if-with-multiple-criteria/ Afterwards, all you need to do is compare if the Update Date is equal to th new column or if they are different (in which case you want to delete the row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want to do is to read all rows and iterate through each duplicate row and find what to keep, what to delete based on finding the highest update_date.

I have successfully wrote a macro to do that. Here is my code:

**First**: Create a blank Module in the VBA Editor and paste the following code:

```
Public Type Row

    id As String
    updated As Date

    row_number As Integer    'to know which rows to delete later
    is_duplicate As Boolean  'to mark if current row is duplicate
    to_keep As Boolean       'to decide whether to keep or to delete
    verified As Boolean      'needed to avoid evaluating all rows with the same ID

End Type



Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Range("a2").Select    'go to first row
Dim cnt As Integer    'keep record of how many rows
cnt = 0               'begin with an empty array
Dim rows() As Row     'declared without the count


'== step 1: read all data and store in array ===============
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    cnt = cnt + 1
    ReDim Preserve rows(cnt)   'expand the size of the array by ONE
    rows(cnt - 1).row_number = ActiveCell.Row   'keep record of current row address

    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value Or _
       ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value Then

       'if the cell above/below has the samve ID as the current cell, then it's duplicates

        rows(cnt - 1).is_duplicate = True
    Else
        rows(cnt - 1).is_duplicate = False
    End If

    rows(cnt - 1).id = ActiveCell.Value                   'store the id
    rows(cnt - 1).updated = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value 'store the date
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select                        'move to the next row below
Loop


'=== step 2: iterating throw the array and deciding what to keep, what to delete =========
For i = 0 To cnt - 1
    If rows(i).is_duplicate And Not rows(i).verified Then
        'the current ID is duplicated, and all of the other rows with the same ID has not been verified
        find_to_keep rows, rows(i).id, cnt   'helper Sub to analyze each row

    End If
Next


'==== step 3: iterating throw the array to delete ones marked to delete ==========

For i = cnt - 1 To 0 Step -1  'we have to reverse the order because deleted rows will contain data from other valid rows

    If rows(i).is_duplicate And Not rows(i).to_keep Then
        'if the current row is duplicate and is not marked (to keep) then it must be deleted

        Dim r As Integer
        r = rows(i).row_number   'get the rows number (address) of the row

        Range(r & ":" & r).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp   'delete the row and shift the other rows below UP

    End If

Next

End Sub

Sub find_to_keep(ByRef rows() As Row, ByVal id As String, ByVal cnt As Integer)
    Dim max_date As Date   'temparary variable to hold the maximum date

    Dim to_keep As Integer  'temporary variable to hold the location of row to keep


    ' -- step a: go throw the array and find all rows with id specified in the sub parameter
    For i = 0 To cnt - 1
        If rows(i).id = id Then
            'if that row has a date that is higher than our current max_date, the read its date
            If rows(i).updated > max_date Then
                max_date = rows(i).updated
                to_keep = i
            End If
        End If
    Next



    '-- step b: now that we know what row to keep, we need to do:
    '           1- mark all other rows having the same ID as verified (to avoid looping through them again)
    '           2- mark the row with the highest date to (to_keep) = true

    For i = 0 To cnt - 1
        If rows(i).id = id Then
            If i = to_keep Then
                rows(i).to_keep = True
            Else
                rows(i).to_keep = False
            End If
            rows(i).verified = True

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is what it looks like: [image: screenshot of excel result]

And if you like, I have attached the entire workbook for your reference: [remove_Duplicates.xlsm](http://goo.gl/ct3Lxe)

Comment: Sorry I accidentally offset the column for the update date check to the wrong column! It does work. Thanks, Great Answer!